# how to filter specific course by specific year in one mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli, concatenation

I'm working out on a website that required me to display specific course with specifically by year only in one table.

here's some details from my table:

**Table student**

**stdID, stdCourseDesc, accessDate**

12211, Aircraft Maintenance License Program ? EASA Part 66, 2018-3-6

12212, Aircraft Maintenance License Program ? EASA Part 66, 2015-8-6

12213, Diploma in Aircraft Maintenance Technology (Manufacturing), 2017-3-1

12214, Master of Business Administration (Entrepreneurship), 2018-1-16

12215, Aircraft Maintenance License Program ? EASA Part 66, 2015-10-1

12216, Aircraft Maintenance License Program ? EASA Part 66, 2016-12-10

12217, Doctor of Philosophy (Manufacturing), 2016-5-14

I only manage to codes until this but of course it only display the course.

```
SELECT CONCAT(`stdCourseDesc`, ', ', `accessDate`) AS byYear FROM student WHERE `stdCourseDesc` = 'Aircraft Maintenance License Program ? EASA Part 66'
```

I tried this but failed.

```
SELECT CONCAT(stdCourseDesc, ', ', accessDate) AS byYear FROM student where `stdCourseDesc` = 'Aircraft Maintenance License Program ? EASA Part 66', YEAR(`accessDate`)=2015
```

I will using this code to display the output

```
$conn = new mysqli ('localhost', 'root', '', 'dashboard');

$aircraftyear2015 = $conn ->query ("SELECT CONCAT(`stdCourseDesc`, ', ', 
`accessDate`) AS byYear FROM student WHERE `stdCourseDesc` = 'Aircraft 
Maintenance License Program ? EASA Part 66'");
$aircraftyear2016 = $conn ->query ("SELECT CONCAT(`stdCourseDesc`, ', ', 
`accessDate`) AS byYear FROM student WHERE `stdCourseDesc` = 'Aircraft 
Maintenance License Program ? EASA Part 66'");
$aircraftyear2017 = $conn ->query ("SELECT CONCAT(`stdCourseDesc`, ', ', 
`accessDate`) AS byYear FROM student WHERE `stdCourseDesc` = 'Aircraft 
Maintenance License Program ? EASA Part 66'");
$aircraftyear2018 = $conn ->query ("SELECT CONCAT(`stdCourseDesc`, ', ', 
`accessDate`) AS byYear FROM student WHERE `stdCourseDesc` = 'Aircraft 
Maintenance License Program ? EASA Part 66'");

$tot_aircraftyear2015 = mysqli_num_rows($aircraftyear2016);
$tot_aircraftyear2016 = mysqli_num_rows($aircraftyear2017);
$tot_aircraftyear2017 = mysqli_num_rows($aircraftyear2016);
$tot_aircraftyear2018 = mysqli_num_rows($aircraftyear2017);

<?php echo $tot_aircraftyear2015; ?>
<?php echo $tot_aircraftyear2016; ?>
<?php echo $tot_aircraftyear2017; ?>
<?php echo $tot_aircraftyear2018; ?>
```

How do i want to filtered the specific course by specific year in one mysql table?

Does my code can be use to display data?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it could be a syntax issue, try the following:

```
SELECT CONCAT(stdCourseDesc, ', ', accessDate) AS byYear 
FROM student 
WHERE  `stdCourseDesc` = 'Aircraft Maintenance License Program ? EASA Part 66' 
  AND YEAR(`accessDate`) = '2015'
```